# Checking for instances through the base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

right now I am doing a game which requires Monsters. I made a `MonsterBase` class that every other monster will inherit from. This is a console game so I give every `LowLevelMonster` instance different coordinates.
In a different method I want to check if the player is on the same coordinates as one of the monster instances. Right now i can only use an `if` statement to ask for the `PositionX` & `PositionY` of every monster instance. This scales terribly if I get to over 5 monsters.

**My question**: Since the other monster instances inherit from `MonsterBase`, is it possible to check for the `PositionX` & `PositionY` of `MonsterBase` that calls for *every* inhertied instance of it?

Something like:

```cs
if(Player.PositionX == MonsterBase.PositionX)
{
    Console.WriteLine("the names of the Monsters instances that have the same X Coordinates");
}
```

These are my current classes:

```cs
public class MonsterBase 
{
    int PositionX = 0;
    int PositionY = 0;
}

public class LowLevelMonster : MonsterBase
{
    string name = "monster";
    int HP = 5;
}
```

Comment: where are all the instances? array? list? if so, you can iterate all over and check every single instance for whatever you like condition. Otherwise, you must check one by one.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand the question. Have a collection of monster instances and then iterate over the collection and compare positions? `List<MonsterBase>` `foreach(var monster in monsters) {if(monster.Position == Player.Position) {...}}`

Comment: the instances arent saved into a list or an array. Right now i just wanted to make this work and optimize it later. Adding them into a list doesnt sound like a bad idea, but are there any other more elegant ways using the fact that they inherited from the same base class? In case i do not find anything i will use lists. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @KieranDevlin no, i do not have a collection, but i also did not think about this option (im a beginner and still have bit of troubles with the List<> syntax haha. In case i do not find a more elegant option i will procceed with lists.

Comment: Nope, this isn't how inheritance works, there's no implied link from an instance of the base class to an instance of the child. You are going to have to keep a record of all your monsters in a collection, something like `List<MonsterBase>` or `Collection<MonsterBase>` then you can do `listOfMonsters.Where(monster => monster.PositionX == Player.PositionX)` to filter the list down to only the ones that match the x position.

Comment: @phuzi I didnt know that, thnx for telling me. One more question, i see you use a lambda ?keyword?. I have struggles understanding what they do, or rather what they do in your example. Would you post your answer as an answer to this post so i can mark it as the answer? Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this isn't how inheritance works, there's no implied link from an instance of the base class to an instance of the child.

You are going to have to keep a record of all your monsters in a collection, something like `List<MonsterBase>` or `Collection<MonsterBase>` then you can filter the list.

```
listOfMonsters.Where(monster => monster.PositionX == Player.PositionX)
```

**What is a lambda expression**

Think of a lambda expression as shorthand way to write a method.

Moving the expression `monster => monster.PositionX == Player.PositionX` to a variable will get you

```
Expression<Func<MonsterBase, bool>> lambda =
    monster => monster.PositionX == Player.PositionX;
listOfMonsters.Where(lambda);
```

This is a little easier to see what's happening. `listOfMonsters.Where()` expects a parameter of type `Expression<Func<MonsterBase, bool>>` where the lambda is essentially a method delegate that takes a single parameter (named `monster`) and returns a boolean value.

This could have also been written

```
public class Player() {
    public int PositionX { get; set; }

    public bool ComparePosition(MonsterBase monster){
        return monster.PositionX == Player.PositionX;
    }
}

// then later in the code
listOfMonsters.Where(Player.ComparePosition);
```

This is a different overload of `Where` that takes a method group which is essentially the same as.

```
listOfMonsters.Where(monster => Player.ComparePosition(monster));
```

Comment: A `List`, not being an `IQueryable`, cannot use an overload of `Where` that accepts an expression.  Also, your assertion that an expression is essentially a delegate is *very wrong*.  An expression is in fact *quite different* from a delegate.  Additionally, passing in a method group results in *actually* creating a delete, which *isn't* the same as using a lambda (similar, and not behaviorally different in this particular situation, but still not the same).

Comment: Also this does nothing to address the actual problem statement of the question that checking the position against every single monster individually scales very poorly.

Comment: @Servy Not actually knowing how OP is managing their monsters, given what they have said they  likely have 5 separate variables that they check individually each time.

Comment: @Servy you're right. It should have been `Func<,>` rather than `Expression<Func<,>>`.